# Selenium Java WebDriverWait - cannot access java.util.function

Tags: java, selenium, webdriverwait

When I use WebDriverWait in my Java project, IDEA response is:

```js
Error:(17, 9) java: cannot access java.util.function.Function
  class file for java.util.function.Function not found
```

I use this command in a similar project and I have no problem with it.

```js
    @Test
    public void testLogin () {

    new WebDriverWait(driver,20)
        .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@type='email']")));
    driver.findElement(By.name("email")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys(Email);
    driver.findElement(By.name("password")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys(Password);
    driver.findElement(By.name("submit")).click();
```

Comment: are you using java >= 8?

Comment: @SirLenz0rlot I think you mean Java <= 8 but yes,if your java version is 1.7 or less you can’t use Java.util.function.Function since it was added in version 8.

Comment: @C.Peck I meant the open question I typed :) - but thanks for adding more context

Answer (score 4):

A bit unclear how your project is built, if you have:

- Downloaded the standard *Seleniu-Java* client jars or
- Using *Maven* or *Gradle*

Possibly, you are using *Maven* and as per [Error:(57, 38) java: The type java.util.function.Function cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files](https://github.com/satoshinm/WebSandboxMC/issues/90) this issue is *caused by **Java 1.7** being specified as the target version within **pom.xml**.*

`java.util.function.Function` was added with *Java 1.8*

Solution to this:

- Update to *JDK v1.8*
- If using *Maven*, update:

  ```
  <properties>
      <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
      <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  ```
- If using *Gradle*, add the following to your `build.gradle` file

  ```
  plugins {
       id 'java'
  }

  sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
  targetCompatibility = '1.8'
  version = '1.2.1'
  ```
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* (from *Project* -> *Clean* ...) and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.

Comment: I also had to specify version 1.8 for `maven-compiler-plugin` in pom.xml